# Raspberry Pi 3B: built in wifi not detected

Tags: wireless, raspberrypi

I installed Ubuntu Bionic image for RPI2 and added Wi-Fi driver as instructed at Ubuntu [wiki document](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi). However, when I successfully booted my raspberry pi, Ubuntu won't detect built in Wi-Fi chipset but it detects external USB Wi-Fi dongle.
What should I do?

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -C 
network
 *-network:0
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: eth0
   serial: b8:27:eb:e9:56:7d
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=smsc95xx driverversion=22-Aug-2005 duplex=half firmware=smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
  *-network:1
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 3
   bus info: usb@1:1.3
   logical name: wlan0
   serial: b4:fc:75:a0:0a:dd
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=4.15.0-1010-raspi2 firmware=0.36 ip=172.30.1.30 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dmesg | grep -e 
brcm -e sdio
[    2.164893] brcmvirt-gpio 
soc:virtgpio: Failed to set 
gpiovirtbuf, 
trying to get err:0
[   21.403456] brcmfmac: 
brcmf_fw_map_chip_to_name: using 
brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin for chip 
0x00a9a6(43430) rev 0x000001
[   21.471550] usbcore: registered 
new interface driver brcmfmac
[   25.073769] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: 
Direct firmware load for 
brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.txt failed 
with error -2
[   26.100037] brcmfmac: 
brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout 
(1000000): clkctl 0x50
[   27.135373] brcmfmac: 
brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout 
(1000000): clkctl 0x50
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep -e brcm -e sdio`

Comment: @ktcar214 were you able to find a solution to this?